# How You disppearing a menu list when you zooming in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

[ASK]

How do you guys disappear a Menu List when you zooming in the page?

example:

```
<-- Normal Page [No Zoom] -->

[Logo] Profile Gallery Guestbook


<-- Zoom In 120% -->

[Logo] Profile Guestbook


<-- Zoom In 150% -->

[Logo] Guestbook


<-- Zoom In 200% -->

[Logo]
```

this is my css & div code for it:

```
#nav {list-style-type:none; margin:0px; position:static;}


#nav li a {display:inline-block; width:50; padding: 10 20 10 20; text-align:center;     text-decoration:none; float:left; color:#FFF;}


#nav li a:hover {background:#FFF; color:#000; border-top:3px solid #333;}
```

---

```
<ul id="nav">

<li ><a href="/">Profile</a></li>

<li ><a href="/">Gallery</a></li>

<li ><a href="/">Guestbook</a></li>

</ul>
```

When you zoom in the page, menu disappear automatically with no scrollbar.

For the example, check out http://www.mashable.com navigation manu

Comment: thats due to `overflow:hidden;`, you should know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use well `overflow:hidden;`, structure it well and style it properly also:

### HTML:

```
<div class='nav'>
   <ul>
     <li><a href='#'>One</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Two</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Three</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Four</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Five</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Six</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.nav{width:80%; height:50px; background:#e5e5e5; overflow:hidden;} // wrapper for navigation with overflow hidden
.nav ul{margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; overflow:hidden;} // list parent with overflow hidden too
.nav li{display:inline-block; padding:0 20px; height:50px; line-height:50px;}
```

Although there are more ways doing this but i like to do it this way short and simple.

[**See this in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/A5N6G/)

Answer (score 1):

They are measuring the content width and setting selected menu items to `display: block` via @media rules. E.g.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
    .main-menu>li:nth-child(12) {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

So until the content width is 1300px, the menu item this applies to receives the default `display: none;`